# Selected achor tag value on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a value of anchor tag when mouse hover and values come from autocompleted function .i have a added code but its not give me a value of anchor tag.so how to get value of anchor tags on mouse hover
so please help me
thank you for the advance

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();

        });

        function SearchText() {
            $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Test.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                            $(".ui-autocomplete").addClass("test1");
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                },
                focus: function () {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.value);
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(", ");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $("#txtSearch").bind("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })


            $(function () {
                $(".ui-autocomplete li").hover(function () {
                    var txt = $(this).find('a').html(); // .text(); to get the text in anchors
                    alert(txt);
                });
            });


            function split(val) {
                return val.split(/,\s*/);
            }
            function extractLast(term) {
                return split(term).pop();
            }



$(function () {
                $(".ui-autocomplete li").hover(function () {
                    var txt = $(this).find('a').html(); // .text(); to get the text in anchors
                    alert(txt);
                });
            });

        }
    </script>


                                 HTML

<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all test1" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1;
                    top: -16px; left: 115px; display: none; position: relative; width: 1310px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">City
                        Name</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
            <br>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Agra</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Ahmedabad</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
            <br>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Location
                        Name</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
            <br>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add it into a fiddle or even SO's code snippet thing please.

Comment: The part where you hover should work: https://jsfiddle.net/s69by0y1/